# How to redirect linux command output to logging

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I know this is very simple question but I am not able to make as I am new to python

I have a shell script which generate out put when you execute onlinux shell
generally it takes 30-40 min some more than that too to finish the script.
I am using that script in my python code.
when I execute my python script(say abc.py) the output should redirect to logging instantly also should be printed on screen.

EX: test.sh is shell script and abc.py is my python script.
I can redirect complete output of test.sh to logging as below

```
import logging
import commands
logging,basicConfig(filename=abc.log,filemode='w',level=logging.INFO)
print ("logging started")
status,output=commands.getstatusoutput(./test.sh)
logging.INFO(output)
```

But here two drawbacks:
1) I have to wait till test.sh to be completed to view output in abc.log file but I want to view the output instantly from abc.log
2)Even I cann't view the output on screen instantly , here also I have to wait will it completes.

Can you guide a better way to fulfill my goal.

Comment: Look at the options available in the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, the `subprocess` module is more suited for this. You'll have to read the data from then process through a pipe, and the log and print it.

Here is a working example:

```
import logging
import subprocess

logging.basicConfig(filename='abc.log', filemode='w', level=logging.INFO)
print("logging started")
popen = subprocess.Popen('./script.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in (s.strip('\n').strip('\r') for s in iter(popen.stdout.readline, "")):
    logging.info(line)
    print line
```

The code strips the `\r` and `\n` character from the ends of the string, so that they don't end up in the log or the output.

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for reply , sorry to get back on this such a long time.
Its not working as desired , I want to see the output on console and should be recorded to log at the same time, but it waiting till the script execute and giving the output all at once. and it not working actually so I added shell=True
popen = subprocess.Popen('./script.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fake file-like system

```
class StdoutLogger(object):
"""
 Fake file-like stream object that redirects writes to a logger instance.
"""
   def __init__(self, logger):
       self.logger = logger
   def write(self, buf):
       self.logger.info(buf.strip())
   def flush(self):
       pass
```

Now redirect your stdout to our fake file system

```
logger =  logging.getLogger('stdoutlogger')
sys.stdout = StdoutLogger(logger)
```

Now, even when your script is not completely executed (i.e) even in progress u can read it line by line.